# How to access thread_info from user space

Tags: linux, pthreads

I know Linux maintains `task_struct` (which include `thread_info`) to access different threads. I wonder can a thread itself access its own `thread_info` (Something like `current_thread_info()`).

What I'm trying to do is when I running a thread. I want to know the state of some flags in `thread_info` about the current thread. I checked the API from pthread but I can't find any API for it. So my questions are

1. Can I access the `thread_info` from the current thread (userspace)?
2. If we can't, why Linux didn't provide an API for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you cannot access `thread_info` from userspace (well, other than using privileged kernel tracing/debugging interfaces).

There is no API because it is architecture-specific; most of the flags are only relevant while the task is executing in the kernel; and most importantly it is an internal implementation detail, subject to change at any time.

If you ask another question with the specific flag you're interested in, there might be another way to access that information.

Comment: Thanks, I want to access the `need_resched` flag because I want to let the current thread know if there is going to be a context_switch coming so it can do something. It looks like we don't know when the context_switch will run from the userspace, right?

Comment: @Windsooon: Right, it is never possible to know when a context switch is imminent - not even the kernel knows, because for example at any time a hardware interrupt may occur that results in a higher-priority thread becoming runnable.